# No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I know that there is a lot of questions related to this issue, but none of them  solve my problem. I made a quiz app with 50 questions fragments. In the final question (Question 50 fragment) I call the score Activity to show the score. In this Activity I created a "Play Again" button, which calls the Main Activity again to start the game. But everytime I click on "Play Again" button, my app crashes.

Logcat error: `04-03 15:34:43.638 26316-26316/com.example.moresche.englishqigame E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.moresche.englishqigame.MainActivity }`

scoreActivity.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);

    Typeface mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"chlo.TTF");
    TextView myTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtla);
    myTextview.setTypeface(mTypeface);

    Typeface m2Typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"chlo.TTF");
    TextView m2yTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtla1);
    m2yTextview.setTypeface(m2Typeface);
    initControls();



}




public void initControls() {

     TextView final_score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView103);
    TextView final_scoreqi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView104);
    TextView lvlqi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewzzz);
    Button btnxd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnx);


    final SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    ...

    btnxd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            app_preferences.edit().clear().commit();
            Intent intent1 = new Intent ("com.example.moresche.englishqigame.MainActivity");
            startActivity(intent1);

        }
    });
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.moresche.englishqigame">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".scoreActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.moresche.englishqigame.scoreActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your intent in the wrong way.

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent ("com.example.moresche.englishqigame.MainActivity");
```

It should be something along the lines of:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(scoreActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
```

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Although that will only taking you to the page not play the game again.